# Undefined index: post (wordpress plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

I checked WordPress using query monitoring plug and I got this error:

> Undefined index: post
>   the error in plugin n-custom-point
>   error locations are :

1- wp-content/plugins/n-custom-point/class/metabox-user-group.php:17
prefix_register_meta_boxes()
and this is line 17

```
if($post->ID != $_REQUEST['post']) {
```

2- wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:287
apply_filters('rwmb_meta_boxes')
and this is line 287

```
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
```

3- wp-content/plugins/n-custom-point/inc/meta-box/inc/core.php:50
RWMB_Core->register_meta_boxes()
and this is line 50

```
$configs  = apply_filters( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', array() );
```

4- wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:287
do_action('init')
and this is line 287

```
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
```

5- wp-settings.php:540
and this is line 540

```
do_action( 'init' );
```

I want to know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PHP Notice, it can be fixed by changing the line from:

```
if($post->ID != $_REQUEST['post']) {
```

to

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) && $post->ID != $_REQUEST['post']) {
```

Comment: Ali is notice not a big issue ?  I have another notice saying (Undefined variable: output)  location wp-content/plugins/n-custom-point/n_custom_point.php:1490
n_lottery_winner_list()  and the line 1490  is  $output .= "<table><tr><th>Date</th><th>Lottery</th><th>Winner</th></tr>";
would you please advise

Comment: Notice only report uninitialized and undefined variables, it can help with variable name misspellings also, and it might not cause issues in most cases depending on the application, so it really depends on the use of that reported variable, if it's required for some other functionality, that functionality might not work and without you even noticing it. Generally, it's not a big issue, but it's good to always make sure everything is defined correctly.

Comment: thank you a lot for the clarification , so can you advise how to fix the issue I sent in my previous comment please ?

Comment: You need to declare the variable like this `$output = "";` before line 1490 above the `$output .=...........................`

Comment: would you please right what exactly will be added. sorry I am not programmer thats why I am asking you that

Comment: or you meant to add $output = ""; in line before line 1490 ?

Comment: Yes, you should exactly do that